# Cannot remove the newly added items from a jQuery sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to add and then remove elements / items from a jQuery UI sortable list...

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MvnEv/108/)

```
<div class="add">Click me to add new item to list</div>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on them...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on them...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on them...</div>
    </li>
</ul>

$("#sortable").sortable();

$(".add").click(function () {
    var newItem = '<li class="delete"><div class="item">these <span>new items cannot be removed</span> by click on them...</div></li>';
    $("#sortable").append(newItem);
    $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");

});

$(".delete").click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

to

```
$("#sortable").on('click', ".delete", function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The elements are inserted dynamically and doesn't exist when you attach the event handler, so you have to delegate up to a parent that does exist when you attach the handler.